# How to remove all but the last 3 parts of FQDN?

Tags: bash, awk, sed, cut

I have a list of IP lookups and I wish to remove all but the last 3 parts, so:
98.254.237.114.broad.lyg.js.dynamic.163data.com.cn
would become
163data.com.cn

I have spent hours searching for clues, including parameter substitution, but the closest I got was:

```
$ string="98.254.237.114.broad.lyg.js.dynamic.163data.com.cn"
$ string1=${string%.*.*.*}
$ echo $string1
```

Which gives me the inverted answer of:
98.254.237.114.broad.lyg.js.dynamic
which is everything but the last 3 parts.

A script to do a list would be better than just the static example I have here.
Using CentOS 6, I don't mind if it by using sed, cut, awk, whatever.
Any help appreciated.

---

Thanks, now that I have working answers, may I ask as a follow up to then process the resulting list and if the last part (after last '.') is 3 characters - eg .com .net etc, then to just keep the last 2 parts.

If this is against protocol, please advise how to do a follow up question.

Comment: see https://stackoverflow.com/help/someone-answers... for follow up, ask another question... but add your attempt for modified question as well

Comment: [edit] your question to include concise, testable sample input and expected output that covers all of your use cases so we're not guessing.

Answer (score 2):

```
echo $string | awk -F. '{ if (NF == 2) { print $0 } else { print $(NF-2)"."$(NF-1)"."$NF } }'
```

NF signifies the total number of field separated by "." and so we want the last piece (NF), last but 1 (NF-1) and last but 2 (NF-2)

Comment: Just noticed that it fails on lines that have only 2 fields and doubles them up.  eg 101echo.com becomes 101echo.com.101echo.com

Comment: I've amended to take account of the scenario.

Answer (score 2):

if parameter expansion inside another parameter expansion is supported, you can use this:

```
$ s='98.254.237.114.broad.lyg.js.dynamic.163data.com.cn'
$ # removing last three fields
$ echo "${s%.*.*.*}"
98.254.237.114.broad.lyg.js.dynamic
$ # pass output of ${s%.*.*.*} plus the extra . to be removed
$ echo "${s#${s%.*.*.*}.}"
163data.com.cn
```

can also reverse the line, get required fields and then reverse again.. this makes it easier to use change numbers

```
$ echo "$s" | rev | cut -d. -f1-3 | rev
163data.com.cn
$ echo "$s" | rev | cut -d. -f1-4 | rev
dynamic.163data.com.cn

$ # and easy to use with file input
$ cat ip.txt 
98.254.237.114.broad.lyg.js.dynamic.163data.com.cn
foo.bar.123.baz.xyz
a.b.c.d.e.f
$ rev ip.txt | cut -d. -f1-3 | rev
163data.com.cn
123.baz.xyz
d.e.f
```

Comment: Nice indeed!   The reverse with a list seems to be the best at the moment as it doesn't have problems with less than 3 fields in the original list.

Comment: if you have `perl`, you can use `perl -F'\.' -lane '$n = $F[-1]=~m/.../ ? -2 : -3; print join ".",@F[$n..-1]' ip.txt` where I have also added logic to print only last two fields if last field is 3+ characters

Comment: It appears to be adding a dot to the front of 2 field lines.

So yordt.us becomes .yordt.us

Comment: try with `$n = length($F[-1]) > 2 || $#F == 1 ? -2 : -3;` but that will be issue for single field lines... I think you should let original question stand, experiment yourself with all odd cases and extra requirements like 3 char in last field, etc and then ask new question if you get stuck..

Comment: Yes, I understand and appreciate what you have all contributed.   I can deal with the leading dot in other ways, but the elegance of what you people come up with amazes me.  I had bowel cancer 9 years ago and I have never been as mentally sharp since then, but happy to be alive :)

Answer (score 1):

```
$ echo $string | awk -F'.' '{printf "%s.%s.%s\n",$(NF-2),$(NF-1),$NF}'
163data.com.cn
```

Brief explanation,

- Set the field separator to `.`
- Print only last 3 field using the `awk` parameter `$(NF-2), $(NF-1),and $NF`.

And there's also another option you may try,

```
$ echo $string | awk -v FPAT='[^.]+.[^.]+.[^.]+$' '{print $NF}'
163data.com.cn
```

Comment: Thanks for your prompt reply, the first works well, but not the second, I am trying to feed a list to it.

Comment: Both method should work without problem, and I believe these should work even a list is fed.

Comment: Just noticed that it fails on lines that have only 2 fields and doubles them up. eg 101echo.com becomes 101echo.com.101echo.com

Comment: You should mention that `FPAT` is gawk-only. Always state when a solution is specific to one version of a tool so no-one wastes time trying it on other versions.

Answer (score 1):

It sounds like this is what you need:

```
awk -F'.' '{sub("([^.]+[.]){"NF-3"}","")}1'
```

e.g.

```
$ echo "$string" | awk -F'.' '{sub("([^.]+[.]){"NF-3"}","")}1'
163data.com.cn
```

but with just 1 sample input/output it's just a guess.

wrt your followup question, this might be what you're asking for:

```
$ echo "$string" | awk -F'.' '{n=(length($NF)==3?2:3); sub("([^.]+[.]){"NF-n"}","")}1'
163data.com.cn

$ echo 'www.google.com' | awk -F'.' '{n=(length($NF)==3?2:3); sub("([^.]+[.]){"NF-n"}","")}1'
google.com
```

Answer (score 0):

Version which uses only `bash`:

```
echo $(expr "$string" : '.*\.\(.*\..*\..*\)')
```

To use it with a file you can iterate with `xargs`:

File:

```
head list.dat
98.254.237.114.broad.lyg.js.dynamic.163data.com.cn
98.254.34.56.broad.kkk.76onepi.co.cn
98.254.237.114.polst.a65dal.com.cn
```

iterating the whole file:

```
cat list.dat | xargs -I^ -L1 expr "^" : '.*\.\(.*\..*\..*\)'
```

Notice: it won't be very efficient in large scale, so you need to consider by your own whether it is good enough for you.

Regexp explanation:

```
.*  \.  \(  .*  \.  .*  \.  .*   \)
\___|    |       |       |        |
    |    \------------------------/> brakets shows which part we extract
    |            |       |
    |            \-------/> the \. indicates the dots to separate specific number of words
    |
    |
    -> the rest and the final dot which we are not interested in (out of brakets)
```

details:
http://tldp.org/LDP/abs/html/string-manipulation.html -> Substring Extraction

Comment: Nice, but how would I feed it a list?